# How to show attribute value within the Temando Shipping module?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm having an issue with customizing the Temando Shipping module. I simply want to populate the below fields with the corresponding attribute value:

- Description
- Composition
- HS Code
- Country of Manufacture
- Country of Origin

All of the attributes have been created and the product(s) show their relevant values on the admin product page.

I have tried to incorporate it directly into the module but everything I have tried fails, I was hoping some support is available from here.

I have attached a screengrab of the Admin area in question.

[image: Screengrab for attribute issue]

Any help on this would be brilliant.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

The Temando company ceased operations on 25th September 2019.

I suspect their servers have stopped receiving API calls.  The extent of the fallout on the Magento Shipping product (amongst other services) are yet to be determined.

Your Magento Account Manager maybe be able to help further.